# How to execute a fetchRequest count for each object from array?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have 2 Entities:

Attendace:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Attendance {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var id_consultant: String?
    @NSManaged var id_store: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var status: String?

}
```

and Product :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Product {

    @NSManaged var id: String?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var preco: String?
    @NSManaged var attendance: Attendance?

}
```

I'm fetching all Attendances and need to execute a fetch to count how many products are there in a Attendance:

There's my method to fetch the Attendances. How could I get the count of products with the Attendance ID?

```
  func fetchAttendances() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Attendance")
    let attendancePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id_store == \(Int(Helper.userDefaults().objectForKey(ConstantHelper.kIdStore)! as! NSNumber))")
    fetchRequest.predicate = attendancePredicate

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        myAttendances = results as! [NSManagedObject]



        self.collectionAttendances.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is an inverse relationship an option?

Comment: Why not use a one-to-many relationship from Attendance to Product so that you don't need to write fetch code, just check the size of the set?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have set up your data model so that Attendance and Product have a one-to-many relationship...

```
Attendance <---->> Product
```

... you can leverage the `map` syntax to accomplish this in a very succinct way:

```
let countArray = attendanceArray.map { ($0.id, $.products?.count ?? 0) }
```

This will return an array of tuples with the id and the count of products.